# how to display video from facebook pages to my website?

Tags: facebook, video, thumbnails

i created pages in facebook.Public can upload video on my page. 
how to display video from facebook pages to my website??(with thumbnail)

Answer (score 2):

use Facebook Graph API.

First, use [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) to get the posts with type **video**, then use [Video](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/) to get the video.

For FQL, I think you have query similar to this:

```
SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=20531316728
```

Thumbnail is in `thumbnail_link`.

For Graph API, you use something like: ( Try it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552/videos) )

```
https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552/videos
```

the thumbnail is at `data > format > picture`

Comment: thx for your reply Shivan, but can u give me example for this case??
i already try use FQL(Facebook Query Language), but i have problem in make thumbnail for video.

Comment: Why do you use FQL instead of Graph API? Graph API has everything done for you, including embed HTML.

Comment: thx again for your reply, can you give me explain use graph API in php code??thx..is it possible to request width and height for thumb from facebook??

Comment: You should at least try first. My hint is: use `cURL` methods to call Graph API, it will return answer in JSON format. Parsing JSON is not difficult in PHP. Width & height is at `data > format > width` and `data > format > height`

Comment: ok thax a lot shivan,i am succsess for load video..but i need video contain like button, so public user can like.what must i do??thx

Comment: Read : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/ , in specific, Likes > Create section.

Comment: i use success for FQL not graph api,can explain me for my case..thx

Comment: ok i already sucsess for like button case, i want load all video from my page, but only video posted by admin(me) as result. i have setting for public user allow to post video to my page..what wrong with me??thx for your attention

Comment: just a quick note. I'm busy these 2 days. hope I or other guys can reply you very soon. You are close to answer. Double check API to see if you missed anything, e.g. permission.

Comment: still problem about the permission, i don't why??..i already set public user allow to upload video, but when i try to load all video, only video posted by admin loaded

Comment: i try use graph api,but when use this code 'https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/videos',need token. Can u tell how me get token??what the function of token?? thx for your attention

Comment: Most function calls need Access Token. See this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a simple trick that will let you embed any Facebook video into your web pages.

facebook videos

Every video uploaded on to Facebook has a unique ID that you can find in the browser’s address bar (look for the value of parameter "v").

Copy that number and replace it with xxx in the code below.

```
<object width="400" height="224" >
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
 <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" />
 <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
   allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="224">
 </embed>
</object>
```

[source](http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-facebook-videos-in-web-pages/9715/)

Comment: ok sorry I just provide the information I have found (see source) 
(i have remove "Facebook doesn’t (officially) provide an embed code for their videos")